# cdlatex to insert math template

Tags: latex

I am using `cdlatex` to insert `\frac{}{}`.

I have tried doing this inside a math environment:

```
\[ fr<TAB> \]
```

The cursor jumps to after the closing `\]` while the `fr` is not expanded.

I have checked that `cdlatex-mode` is enabled: things like  `` `a `` expand to `\alpha` and `equ<TAB>` expands to an equation environment.

I have checked that `TAB` is bound to the command `cdlatex-tab` in the context above. I have even called the `cdlatex-tab` manually by typing

```
\[ fr<M-x cdlatex-mode RET> \]
```

and I get the same behavior: the cursor point jumps to after the closing `\]` while the `fr` remains unexpanded. It is as if `fr` is not defined in the table but `C-c ?` which shows the table says:

```
...
fr  Insert \frac{}{}  /MATH
...
```

There is nothing extra around the `fr` as shown by the edited portion of the `od -c` output of the `LaTeX` file:

```
...
    0002000   \   [       a   =   -   \   s   q   r   t   {   2   }       \
    0002020   ]   .  \n  \n   \   [       f   r       \   ]  \n  \n   \   e
    0002040   n   d   {   d   o   c   u   m   e   n   t   }  \n
    0002055
```

Why does the `fr` remain unexpanded when I press `TAB` after it?

*EDIT*: In response to questions in the comments:

- `cdlatex-tab-hook` is nil.
- the value of `(assoc "fr"  cdlatex-command-alist-comb)` is `("fr" "Insert \\frac{}{}" "\\frac{?}{}" cdlatex-position-cursor nil nil t)` as expected.

Comment: It works fine here. I don't understand why it does not work for you. I would use `edebug` on the `cdlatex-tab` command to see where it fails.

Comment: By all rights, the expansion should happen. I have no idea why it does not. If you can, please `edebug` the command `cdlatex-tab` and step through it to see where it goes off the rails.

Comment: What should I do exactly to edebug on `cdlatex-tab`?  What command should I execute?

Comment: You need to go to the definition of `cdlatex-tab`: do `C-h f cdlatex-tab` to get its help and then click on the link at the end of the first line of the help buffer to get there. At that point, do `M-x edebug defun` to instrument the function `cdlatex-tab`. Now go back to your LaTeX buffer and type `\[ fr<TAB>`; `cdlatex-tab` will be called and it will *stop* before the first form (the `(catch 'stop ...` form) of the function. You can now press `<Space>` to slowly step through the function. Every time you press <Space>, execution will advance one step.

Comment: When you are done, do `M-x edebug-remove-instrumentation RET` to remove the `edebug` instrumentation. Read [Edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html) in the Emacs Lisp manual for all the gory details.

Comment: That should be `edebug-defun` with a dash.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I did solve it.  After getting some dependency from auctex.  Perhaps Carston can clean such problems up.

Comment: Did you open a bug report?

Comment: With Carston, but do not know if he takes these things seriously.

Comment: Are you talking about `texmathp.el`?

Comment: Right.  I am talking about `texmathp.el`,  He should really package all the emacs things on `tex` together.

Comment: An interesting package, ```latex-auto-activating-snippets``` is here: https://github.com/tecosaur/LaTeX-auto-activating-snippets, could be used instead ```CDLaTeX ``` - but I suggest to add also ```doom-snippets``` to that package(s).